# Simply update label in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5

I have created a label with Qt Creator using a unique name, 'statusLabel'.

I then made a function to update this status label like so:

```
//Function to set the text in the status bar.
void AutoFish::updatelabel(QString str)
{
    ui->statusLabel->setText(str);
}
```

This does not work and gives the following error:

```
C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\AutoFish\autofish.cpp:24: error: C2227: left of '->statusLabel' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I'm just trying to update the label text using that function. Should I be using something other than a label? I've been looking into slots to create an event to update the label, but most slot examples I find involve a pushButton as an event start, and that is not what I need.

Thank you.

EDIT: As per request, here is all of my source code(it's not very big): http://pastebin.com/CfQXdzBK

Comment: Interesting. Apparently, `ui` is a pointer, so you need to access it using `->`. Try to add `ui->statusLabel->setText("Hello");` just under `ui->setupUi(this);` line.

Comment: And can you post your header file which contains declaration of this class?

Comment: @Nemanja It is posted!

Comment: hope everything is fine now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your method is declared as `static`, you can't acces non-static member `ui` directly.

Change

```
static void AutoFish::updatelabel(QString str);
```

to

```
void updatelabel(QString str);
```

in your header file.

There is no need for `static` keyword, because you want to set label for the specific instance of the window. Also, there is no need for `AutoFish::` as you are declaring a method inside class declaration (however, you **do** need it in your cpp file).

As per the second error - inside your `getWindow` function, you need to have a instance of the `AutoFish` object in order to call `updateLabel`. So, either change your `getWindow` definition to:

```
HWND getWindow(AutoFish *af, LPCSTR processName)
{
   HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(0, processName);
    if(!hwnd) {
        std::cout << "Error: Cannot find window!" << std::endl;
        af->updatelabel("Error: Cannot find window.");
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Seccess! Window found!" << std::endl;
        af->updatelabel("Seccess! Window Found!");
    }
    return hwnd;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
HWND window = getWindow(this, "FFXIVLauncher");
```

or make `getWindow` member of `AutoFish` class:

```
class AutoFish : public QMainWindow
{
   // ...
   HWND getWindow(LPCSTR processName);
   // ...
};

HWND AutoFish::getWindow(LPCSTR processName) {
    HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(0, processName);
    if(!hwnd) {
        std::cout << "Error: Cannot find window!" << std::endl;
        updatelabel("Error: Cannot find window.");
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Seccess! Window found!" << std::endl;
        updatelabel("Seccess! Window Found!");
    }
    return hwnd;
}
```

and `this` pointer will be implicitely passed to the `getWindow`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I get the following error with this code: C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\AutoFish\autofish.cpp:24: error: C2228: left of '.statusLabel' must have class/struct/union

Comment: @Vektor Ok, do you have `ui` field in your `AutoFish` class? Can you post the declaration of the class in your question?

Comment: It is posted in the question. Thanks again.

Comment: is there a statusLabel in the ui?

Comment: Now I get the following error: C2352: 'AutoFish::updatelabel' : illegal call of non-static member function. And here is the code I use in another function to call the updatelabel function: AutoFish::updatelabel("Error: Cannot find window.");

Comment: Just use `updateLabel("Error: Cannot find window.");` if that function is in the same class.

Comment: @rathet freak Yes, I created the label with a unique objectName in the Qtcreator Design editor.

Comment: @Nemanja When I remove the 'AutoFish::' from calling the function I get the following error: C3861: 'updatelabel': identifier not found

Comment: Ok, then you need to show us more code. You need to call `updateLabel` on the instance of `AutoFish` class . Show us the declaration of the class where you are calling `updateLabel` and the function where you are calling it.

Comment: @NemanjaBoric Here is all of my source code, it's not very big. http://pastebin.com/CfQXdzBK Thanks so much for your help, and don't be surprised if it's a simple solution as I'm brand new to Qt.